# Webpack & sourcemaps?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I'm currently using `windows.onerror` to log our javascript errors in production. I'm using webpack to bundle our javascript and using the uglify plugin to minify. Unfortunately the [ErrorEvent](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#the-errorevent-interface) object's `lineno` and `columno` are coming from the minified blob produced by webpack. Webpack is producing its default sourcemap files. Is there anyway to get the correct `lineno` and `columno`?

```
w.addEventListener("error", handleError, true);

function handleError(e) {

    let errorToLog = {};

    if (e.message) {
        errorToLog.ErrorMessage = e.message;
    }

    if (e.filename) {
        errorToLog.source = e.filename;
    }

    if (e.lineno) {
        errorToLog.lineNumber = e.lineno;
    }

    if (e.colno) {
        errorToLog.columnNumber = e.colno;
    }

    if (e.error.stack) {
        errorToLog.stackTrace = e.error.stack;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use webpack's [`devtool'](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) setting to add a source map:

```
{
    devtool: "#inline-source-map"
}
```

Note that using a full source map will add an overhead to your transpile time, so if you can live without the column number during development, use the faster `cheap-module-inline-source-map` instead:

```
{
    devtool: "#cheap-module-inline-source-map"
}
```

Comment: Is that the only difference between the two?

Comment: @adam-beck [yep](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html). `cheap-source-map` without the `module` part is when webpack starts discarding real, useful data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible problems.

The most common is that `uglify` now requires an explicit `sourcemap: true` or it will break your source map generation.  The default is now `false`, because, er, reasons.